# notify/subscribe across different service/install implementations

Tags: pip, virtualenv, puppet

I'm working on a fork of a sentry module for puppet (https://github.com/thomasvs/puppet-sentry)

Since Sentry has a lot of dependencies, contrary to my usual approach of installing packages only, this module uses virtualenv and pip to install from requirements.txt as one of the options.

In addition, the service is managed through supervisor instead of a normal service script on a RedHat-based system.

Now, I want to add a way for the service to be restarted when requirements.txt changes; this should only happen though if the install method is venv (for virtual env, using requirements.txt) and the service method is supervisor.

That means I cannot add the notify explicitly in either class, as the specific install method is supposed to be unaware of the specific service method and vice versa.

Ideally, I would want sentry::service::supervisor to subscribe to `sentry::install` (generically) so that if any implementation of `sentry::install` (in particular, venv) changes, the service gets restarted.

As an additional complication, I can't do the reverse in this case (notify from requirements.txt to `sentry::server`), as the File resource for requirements.txt is declared in another class from another module, so I can't add to its notify.